# Uncaught TypeError: chrome.storage.sync.get(...) is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, content-script

I'm trying to make an extension that runs this javascript library, because its not really clear how you run it:

https://github.com/Rio6/Istrolid-js-ai

To do that, I need to run code from storage saved in the popup, but I'm getting this error in the content script:

```
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.storage.sync.get(...) is not a function
```

It says it's on this line of code,

```
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```

Which seems to have nothing to do with the issue. My content script is this:

```
console.log("importing AI library");

var script = document.createElement('script');

console.log(script);

script.src = "https://rawgit.com/Rio6/Istrolid-js-ai/master/r26Ai.js";

var code = document.createElement('script');

console.log(code);

chrome.storage.sync.get("code", (data) => {code.innerHTML = data[0].code; console.log(data[0].code)})

(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(code);
```

Comment: The DOM script element runs in page context, it's no longer an extension's content script so it can't access chrome.storage. See also [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thats the question I used, just modified the second method. Also, I'm trying to set the innerHTML from the content script, not the script tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon at this line:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("code", (data) => {code.innerHTML = data[0].code; console.log(data[0].code)})
```

and so it get interpreted as

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("code", (data) => {code.innerHTML = data[0].code; console.log(data[0].code)})(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```